# En Android ¿para la view EditText cual inputType es el mejor para Nombres y Apellidos?

Tags: android

Cordial saludo,
para la vista EditText (¿si se le llama vista al EditText?) 
cual es el mejor value para el atributo inputType, para el ingreso de Nombres y Apellidos, quiero que al comienzo y siempre despues de un espacio la primera letra sea mayuscula. muchas gracias.

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNombres"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType=""
    android:hint="@string/Nombres"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor valor para tu inputType depende del uso que se le quiera dar.
En tu caso y mediante **xml**, uno apropiado a lo que buscas sería uno combinado con 2 valores.

> `android:inputType="textCapWords|textAutoCorrect"`
>
> El cual es autocorrector y te pondrá cada una de la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula.

---

*Programáticamente* se haría de esta manera.

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                           |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

Comment: Hola, el textAutoCorrect que es lo que hace? por que puse el textCapWords y este solito me pone siempre las primera letras en mayuscula, pero no se para que es el otro. gracias!

Comment: Digamos que te auto corrige a la hora de escribir, pero no obstante te lo puse para que vieras que se pueden combinar varios. Saludos y si crees que se te ha respondido adecuadamente da por finalizada la pregunta y pulsa en la palomita.

Comment: pero me autocorrije, hacia que corrección es lo que no entiendo

Comment: Supongo que por ejemplo estás escribiendo 'Diego' y pones 'Diigo' pues se supone lo pondría correctamente sin necesidad de estar borrando.